# How can i splice a object from a "props" array and assign it to a predefined "data" attribute with it being accessible and reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My Component:

```
props: {
    answerOptions: Array
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedOption: null,
      //selectedOption: {}, also not working

    };
  },
  methods: {
    select(option, i){
       //this.selectedOption = this.answerOptions.splice(i, 1); not working     
       //Object.assign(this.selectedOption, this.answerOptions.splice(i, 1)); also not working
       this.selectedOption = Object.assign({}, this.answerOptions.splice(i, 1)); //still not
 working!
     console.log(this.selectedOption) //prints a observable object with alle the correct values
     console.log(this.selectedOption.anyAttribute) //prints undefined

     }
```

edit:
thats where the select function is called:

```
 <div
    ref="option-elems"
    v-on:click="select(option, i)"
    v-for="option, i in answerOptions"
  >
```

The answerOption array gets rendered via a for loop just fine. When the select() Method is called on one of the answerOption objects it removes it from the array and updates that rendered list in the ui correctly. I can even conditionally render (v-if="selectedOption") with the selectedOption Object. But for the love of god, im am not able to access any of its Attributes like so: {{ selectedOption.anyAttribute }}
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: can u add code where you are calling select method

Comment: okay, i got what i want by not using the returned option object of the splice method but using the option object from the function parameter. (this.selectedOption = option). But the question why i can't use the spliced value still stands.

Comment: splice is used for arrays, but you're trying to assign it to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the object inside the array that is called "selectedOption". When you define this, you are still having the object wrapped in an array, so simply get its first item:

```
this.selectedOption = answers.splice(i, 1)[0];
```

[Demo Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-kirch-zxtbv?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:466-512)